# How to shorten IntoIterator<Item=MyComplexType>

Tags: rust, traits

Typical use case is

```rust
fn process_items(items: impl IntoIterator<Item=MyComplexType>) {...}
```

I wonder if this could this be shortened to

```rust
fn process_items(items: impl ItemsIter) {...}
```

However

```rust
type ItemsIter = IntoIterator<Item=MyComplexType>
```

does not work and helper trait

```rust
trait ItemsIter: IntoIterator<Item=MyComplexType> {}
```

requires a blanket implementation. Is there a better way?

Comment: What's the problem with `ItemsIter` requiring a blanket implementation?

Comment: Blanket is fine - I was wondering if there exists something even better of which I am not aware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to other answers, note that the ability to make a "[trait alias](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/unstable-book/language-features/trait-alias.html)" does exist, but is unstable. If you're on nightly and fine with using unstable features, you can do e.g.

```
#![feature(trait_alias)]

pub struct MyComplexType;

trait MyComplexIterator = IntoIterator<Item = MyComplexType>;
```

([Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=46295c56e539042d4d14e41a0f00d9d2))

Comment: Accepted because it meets my criteria of being a better way of which I didn’t know and I hope it will be stabilized in a not too distant future.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a type alias for `MyComplexType`, and a `where` clause to move the trait bound out of the function parameter list, e.g.

```
type MyAlias = MyComplexType;

fn process_items<I>(items: I)
where
    I: IntoIterator<Item = MyAlias>
{...}
```

If you need this trait bound often, you can also create a custom trait that has the desired trait bound, and provide a blanket implementation for it:

```
trait MyIterator: IntoIterator<Item = MyComplexType> {}
impl<T: IntoIterator<Item = MyComplexType>> MyIterator for T {}

fn process_items(items: impl MyIterator) {...}
```

(You mentioned this in your question; I don't think there's anything wrong with this approach.)

Comment: Blanket is fine - I was wondering if there exists something even better of which I am not aware.